# Understanding recursion in Java a little better

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

Ok I'm really confused about something about recursion in Java. Say I have the following code:

```
static int findShortestString(String[] paths, int lo, int hi) {
        if(lo==hi)
            return lo;
        int minindex=findShortestString(paths,lo+1, hi);
        if(safeStringLength(paths[lo])<safeStringLength(paths[minindex]))
            return lo;
        return minindex;
```

Now the question is not really about the code itself, but just about how recursion works. minindex is being set equal to a recursive call. So the first time the function run and tries to set minindex to something, it does so, and then the function calls itself. But when does the if statement run then? Will it only run when minindex finally actually holds a real value? I just cant wrap my head around this. If minindex causes the function to recurse and recurse, then when will the if statement ever be checked? When `lo==hi`? I dont get it:(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`minindex` is not assigned until `findShortestString` *returns*, which won't happen until `lo == hi`.

Each time the method calls itself, it narrows the difference between `lo` and `hi` by 1, so eventually they'll be equal* and that value will be returned.

An example, with `paths = ["p1", "path2", "longpath3"]`:

```
lo = 0, hi = 2
lo != hi -> call findShortestString(paths, 1, 2)

  lo = 1, hi = 2
  lo != hi -> call findShortestString(paths, 2, 2)

    lo = 2, hi = 2
    lo == hi -> return lo (=2)

  lo = 1, hi = 2, minindex = 2
  length of "path2" < length of "longpath3" -> return lo (= 1)

lo = 0, hi = 2, minindex = 1
length of "p1" < length of "path2" -> return lo (= 0)
```

I've tried to illustrate the variable values at each level of recursion using increasing amounts of indentation. At the beginning of each recursive call, the previous values of `lo`, `hi` and `minindex` are saved off (in a structure called a "stack") and the new values used instead. When each invocation of the method *returns*, the previously saved values are "popped" off the stack for use, and `minindex` assigned from the previous return value.

*unless lo > hi to begin with, I guess...

Answer (score 2):

Here's a play by play of the execution:

You call `findShortestString()` yourself

if lo doesn't not equal hi things continue. Otherwise they stop here and the function returns.

Once you call `findShortestString()` again, everything in this instance of the function completely stops and will not resume until the computer has a value to give `minindex` (aka the function returns.) We start over in a new instance of the function at the top. The only code executed until one of the functions return is the code BEFORE the method call. This could be compared to a while loop.

We only get beyond that line once one of the function instances has `lo==hi` and returns.

Control switches to the function instance before that, which assigns the returned `lo` value to `minindex`.

If `(safeStringLength(paths[lo])<safeStringLength(paths[minindex]))` then we `return lo`. Else, we `return minindex`. Either way, this function instance is complete and control returns to the one before it.

Each function called is now only executing the code AFTER the method call, as the method will not get called again. We are unwinding the stack of calls. All of the returns will now be from the last 2 statements, as the code at the top does not get executed again. Note how only one function instance returns with the top part of the code, terminating the while loop. All the rest terminate with the return statements in the part of the function after the recursive call.

Eventually the last function returns and you go back to the code you called the function from originally.

**Here's a more readable version of what the code is actually doing:**

In the code before the recursive call, all that happens is the creation of a chain of calls until `lo==hi`. Each time the function is called with lo being 1 greater. Here's a sample stack of calls:

```
findShortestString(2,5);
findShortestString(3,5);
findShortestString(4,5);
findShortestString(5,5);
```

When they unwind, each function instance compares the string lengths of the strings at the indexes lo and the index the previous index with the shortest string.

```
compare strings at indexes 2 and 5
if the string at 2 is smaller, compare the strings at indexes 2 and 4.
Otherwise, compare the strings with indexes at 3 and 5.
```

---

If `lo>hi` at the beginning, the code will continue to run until lo overflows an integer and becomes negative, then until lo finally gets all the way up to hi, or 4,94,967,296 - (original lo - original hi). In other words, in will take a **long time**. To fix this, add a check at the beginning of the method that throws an exception if `lo>hi`.

**The code could be better rewritten as this:**

```
static int findShortestString(String[] paths, int lo, int hi) {
    int indexWithShortestString=lo;
    for( int i=lo; i<=hi-1; i++) {
        //assumption: lo and hi are both valid indexes of paths
        if (paths[i+1].length < paths[i].length)
            indexWithShortestString=i+1;
     }
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted to know. Thanks. I'm still analyzing it though to better understand it

Comment: Ok so now when the last function gets a value of lo, and the check is made, what about the other 9 or so recursive calls? What value do they get?

Comment: @fprime, it depends on the list.  If the current element is shorter than `minindex`, it returns `lo`.  Otherwise, it returns `minindex`.

Comment: Ok I tried tracing this out on paper. Instead of explaining all the steps I did, I'll tell you what values I used: lo=2 and hi=6. For minindex, I got a final value of 11. Did I do this right?

Comment: @fprime Good question, answer updated to be a little more clear. :)

Comment: @fprime, SimonJ [gives](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4170207/understanding-recursion-in-java-a-little-better/4170250#4170250) a good example trace.

Answer (score 1):

Think of a stack. Every time the recursive method is called a new "frame" is put on top of the stack. The frame contains its own "slots" for each variable, independent and distinct from those in the frames below.

Eventually, a new frame will be created where the value of `lo` and `hi` are equal, and the method will return *without* pushing another frame. (This is called the "base case".) When that `return` occurs, that frame is popped off the stack, and the frame that was just below it continues its execution at the second `if` statement. Eventually that frame is also popped off and the same happens to the frame just below, and so on, until execution returns to the original caller.

Answer (score 0):

Each time `findShortestString` calls itself, `minindex` will eventually be assigned, then the value is used in the `if` statement.  It is always set the index of the shortest string at a higher index than `lo`.

So if there is a call stack with 10 levels of findShortestString, `minindex` is assigned 9 times (the first call is from another function).

Comment: But then what happens? When is the if checked/

Comment: @fprime, it's checked every time `findShortestString` calls itself.  So again, if you have a 10 element list, the if statement will be executed 9 times.

Answer (score 0):

This is a really confusing recursive function. But you generally have it correct. Every call to findShortestString() will push the function onto the stack. It will keep doing this until lo==hi. At that point, the stack is unwound and corresponding recursive calls will be assigned to their corresponding ints.

In this function, it seems that you'll only ever be returning `lo`. Because either `(safeStringLength(paths[lo])<safeStringLength(paths[minindex])` will be true and you'll return `lo`. Or `lo==hi` will be true and you'll return `lo`

Comment: Whats a good way to trace this on paper? I always try to do a diagram, but it gets messy really quick.

Comment: You can also return `minindex`, in calls other than the base case.

Answer (score 0):

In order for the statement

```
int minindex=findShortestString(paths,lo+1, hi);
```

to evaluate, the method call `findShortestString(paths,lo+1, hi)` must return a value. Thus the following `if` statement will not happen until this method call returns a value. However, this method might call itself again, and you get a nesting effect.

Answer (score 0):

Basically an execution of a function ends when a return statement is called. Everything after a return statement which is called no longer matters (or "exists").

Hence, the local variable minindex will only exist in an execution of a findShortestString function when the first if-statement is false.

Treat each execution of a findShortestString function independently, whether they are called recursively or from somewhere else in the code. i.e. different execution of a findShortestString function may return at different paths and have their own values and local variables. Depending on the input values, they may return at line 3, 6 or 7.

minindenx only exists in an execution that can run line 4, and it is assigned findShortestString(paths,lo+1, hi) which is guaranteed have a value, if the code is correct, otherwise you will get an infinite recursion, resulting in a stack overflow (pun unintended).